# VBA date and Save

Tags: vba

I am trying to build a macro that place the current date (12/15/2012) in one of the cells of the sheet (say A1), saves the sheet as 12.15.2012 then places yesterday's date(12/14/2012) in the same cell, saves the sheet and so forth. How do I do that? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use date functions in conjunction with Format():

```
'This puts yesterdays date in cell A1 and saves the workbook with that format
Private Sub test()
    Range("A1").Value = Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Now()), "dd/MM/yy")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "something" & Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Now()), "dd/MM/yy")
End Sub
```

Now you can just loop over that and do your business.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But instead of "something" as the files name is there a way to save it as the date that was placed into the cell? So for 12/15/2012 ---> 12.15.2012 ? Thank you!

Comment: Also, the date is already in the filename as the code is right now.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to save only the worksheet or the workbook?
For the worksheet you can use:

```
Range("A1").Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
ActiveSheet.Name = Format(Range("A1").Value, "mm.dd.yyyy")
Range("A1").Value = Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Range("A1").Value), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Be careful with the date format, you aren't allowed to use "/" for file name or sheet name.